# Reports for Opens in dark mode and device. Is there such a report in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, reporting, custom-reports

A couple of questions:

1. Is there a report/query available in SFMC to gather users who opened their email in dark mode?
2. Is there a report/query to find out what email clients users opened their email on?

I see there is a performance by device report but it gives you a basic overview of it (Desktop Vs Mobile). Looking for more of a detailed breakdown by email client.
The other option I see but is not available on the client account I'm working for is through Discover Reporting.

If there is a sample query I can look into, that would be helpful!

Let me know and thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to track email client within Marketing Cloud?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/236870/is-there-a-way-to-track-email-client-within-marketing-cloud)

Comment: For one of the accounts we had a custom report created that showed details of the device and email client (no “dark mode” insights though). Reach out to support to see if they can create a report like that for you - this was paid extra if I remember correctly.

Comment: Honestly, for the device stuff, I would look at utilizing EmailOnAcid or Litmus as it is a more accurate representation than what is collected by SFMC. Secondly, there is no way to tell Dark Mode as it is based on the client's preferences set in the browser/client - which for security reasons is not shared back or trackable.

Comment: If you truly need it, I believe you can get this info via a Tracking Extract as well, but as I said it is not a focus for SFMC, so the info is more of a general guide, not an accurate portrayal.